# API called twice in nuxt js 3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

[image]

If I submit the form, the submitForm function is called 1 time, but the API inside the submitForm function has been called 2 times.

The first response was 204 and the Second response was 200.

Anyone can help me. I would like to call API only once on button click.